# sorting pandas multiindex once for every group

Tags: python, pandas

Here's the df:

```
                    'A'         'B
Gain/Expsr% -10.0   2.104000    1.194000
            -2.0    1.389000    0.892000

Gain/MaxDD  -10.0   0.024000    0.064000
            -2.0    0.020000    0.058000
```

And expected output is:

```
                    'A'         'B
Gain/Expsr%  -2.0   1.389000    0.892000
             -10.0  2.104000    1.194000

Gain/MaxDD  -2.0    0.020000    0.058000
            -10.0   0.024000    0.064000
```

I've tried with little success:

```
 df.sortlevel(axis=1,level=[1,0],sort_remaining=True)
 df.sort_index(axis=1,level=1,sort_remaining=True)
```

and something along the lines of:

```
 df.reset_index(level=1,inplace=True)
 df['level_1'] = df['level_1'].values[::-1]
 df.reindex(df, level=0)
```

Comment: How do you want to sort this dataframe?  Your expected output both groups are sorted differently?

Comment: Yes, i dont want level 0 to change, but every level 1  (within a level 0 group) to be reversed

Comment: That is not what your expected output is showing.  Exp is descending, MaxDD is ascending.

Comment: oops I will fix

Comment: alright lol sorry about that, both descending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try with `ascending` as list:

```
df.sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True,True])

                       A      B
Gain/Expsr% -10.0  2.104  1.194
            -2.0   1.389  0.892
Gain/MaxDD  -10.0  0.024  0.064
            -2.0   0.020  0.058
```

and

```
df.sort_index(level=[0,1], ascending=[True, False])

                       A      B
Gain/Expsr% -2.0   1.389  0.892
            -10.0  2.104  1.194
Gain/MaxDD  -2.0   0.020  0.058
            -10.0  0.024  0.064
```

Comment: thanks - didn't know you could pass ascending as a list, but makes total sense that you should be able to

Comment: Yeah, I was just demonstrating the different sorts. :)